# 協力する particle usage

Tags: grammar, nuances, particle-に, particle-と

> 私**と**協力してください。
>   私**に**協力してください。
>   Please cooperate with me.

Is there any difference in meaning/usage/nuance when choosing と or に to go with the verb 協力する?

If I had to guess maybe I'd say that 私**と**協力してください would mean "please let's work equally together". Whereas 私**に**協力してください would be "please give your cooperation to me". So と would sound a bit more gentle, maybe?

A google search shows that に is more common but I suspect that might be because of adverbs ending in に.

How about this sentence:

> 世界の国が行う宇宙の調査に協力します

Does this read more like "cooperate with" or "contribute to"? Can I replace に with と here?

Comment: I don't know about 私と vs 私に. Personally, 私と協力してください sounds better to me. But 世界の国が行う宇宙の調査に協力します is different and there's no ambiguity: "We are participating **in** the investigations of the universe that are being conducted by the nations of the world"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between 私と協力してください and 私に協力してください is small, and they are usually interchangeable. While the latter is simple "please help me", the former does sound more like "let's do it *together with* me", although saying "equally" would be a bit too much.

In 世界の国が行う宇宙の調査に協力します, you cannot replace this に with と, because you won't do something together with the 調査 itself.